# How to make marginal boxes that respect page breaks

Tags: boxes, marginpar, marginnote

At the moment, I'm using a combination of `\makebox` and `\parbox` to insert labels into the margin in my thesis. For the most part, this works, but occasionally I have a long label that doesn't quite fit within the text area, as in the picture below.

What would be a better way of trying to do this, that would respect page breaks? Perhaps `marginpar` or `marginnote` might be cajoled into doing what I want? (I originally created my own solution because I needed exact control of the vertical positioning.)

[image]

(Apologies for the lack of MWE, but in this case I think I would need a total rewrite of the code.)

Comment: The mwe also saves us the trouble of creating our own test data.

Comment: If you measure the size of the note, you can use the needspace package to force a page break.